# Filter the device screen size on the Android Market

Tags: android, google-play, android-market-filtering

I want my app available on 7 inches tablets and bigger, the following code exclude lot of tablets like the Galaxy tab 7, HTC Flyer, etc.

```
 <supports-screens android:smallScreens="false" 
                   android:normalScreens="false" 
                   android:largeScreens="true" 
                   android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

and if i set `android:normalScreens` to true, all the phones (and of course the 7 inch tablets) can see the app.

Is there a way to do what I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly filter devices in publisher console. Just allow any device in manifest file and filter in market. It's not the best way, but if you want such specific filter - you can use it. [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the screensize with the screen density, see android:requiresSmallestWidthDp on:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html

Comment: Google says :    "However, Android Market currently does not support this attribute for filtering (on Android 3.2), so you should continue using the other size attributes if your application does not support small screens" I try tu use this attribute but it didn't change anything